# Recursion in MergeSort

Tags: c++

I edited my code, removed the obvious mistakes. but i am still not able to find why my mergesplit function is not recursive. It is only executing once. Please if some one can give me a detailed solution.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

void Merge_Sort(int a[],int p,int q,int mid);

void Merge_Split(int a[],int p,int q)//recursive function
{
 int mid;
 if (p<q)
 {
  mid=(p+q)/2;
  Merge_Split(a,p,mid);
  Merge_Split(a,mid+1,q);
  Merge_Sort(a,p,q,mid);
 }
 return;
}

void Merge_Sort(int a[], int p,int q,int mid)//sorting function
{
 int b[50];
 int i,j,x;
 for(i=p,j=mid+1,x=p;i<=mid,j<q;)
 {
  if(a[j]<=a[i])
    b[x++]=a[j++];
  else
    b[x++]=a[i++];
 }
 while(i<=mid)
 {
  b[x++]=a[i++];
 }
 while(j<=q)
 {
  b[x++]=a[j++];
 }
 for(int i=p;i<q;i++)
  a[i]=b[i];
}

int main()
{
 int a[5],x=0,n=5;
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   scanf("%d", &a[i]);
 Merge_Split(a,0,5);
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   printf("%d", a[i]);
 return 0;
}
```

This code should work fine. I am not able to find out my problem. Kindly help.

Comment: `b[x++]==a[j++]`, this doesn't assign, `==` is a comparison operator not an assignment operator. In addition tagging this with c++11 seems quite misleading.

Comment: Your code never calls Merge_Split, and only calls Merge_Sort once (no recursion).

Comment: jack thanks for pointing that mistake, and n.m can u explain a bit more? i mean i just swapped the merge sort function with the split one. I am still getting the same result

Comment: @ANURAGKUMAR You are calling Merge_Sort instead of Merge_Split from your main. I would advise you to use gdb to debug further.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up with open/closed intervals. Once you make a convention on what type your interval is, you keep your code consistent with your convention.

`Merge_Split(a,0,5)` indicates you want to use left-closed, right-open intervals.

In that case:

`if (p<q)`

```
Merge_Split(a,p,mid);
Merge_Split(a,mid,q);
Merge_Sort(a,p,q,mid);
```

And:

`for(i=p,j=mid,x=p;i<mid,j<q;)`

`while(i<mid)`

Full code with those changes:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

void Merge_Sort(int a[],int p,int q,int mid);

void Merge_Split(int a[],int p,int q)//recursive function
{
 int mid;
 if (p<q - 1)
 {
  mid=(p+q)/2;
  Merge_Split(a,p,mid);
  Merge_Split(a,mid,q);
  Merge_Sort(a,p,q,mid);
 }
 return;
}

void Merge_Sort(int a[], int p,int q,int mid)//sorting function
{
 int b[50];
 int i,j,x;
 for(i=p,j=mid,x=p;i<mid,j<q;)
 {
  if(a[j]<=a[i])
    b[x++]=a[j++];
  else
    b[x++]=a[i++];
 }
 while(i<mid)
 {
  b[x++]=a[i++];
 }
 while(j<q)
 {
  b[x++]=a[j++];
 }
 for(int i=p;i<q;i++)
  a[i]=b[i];
}

int main()
{
 int a[5],x=0,n=5;
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   scanf("%d", &a[i]);
 Merge_Split(a,0,5);
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
   printf("%d", a[i]);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing what u told me but my code still doesnt runs. Infact now the code just stops working upon entering the elements in the array. :(